# How do I perform outstanding entity updates after 8.7?

Tags: entities, database, drush

I have just tested the update to 8.7.1 (from 8.6.x) which includes the removal of the old automatic entity update functionality, which means `drush entup` no longer works. As far as I understand the [change record](https://www.drupal.org/node/3034742), developers now need to perform the updates inside update hooks. However, after updating the core with composer and performing the database update (which ran without any errors), I get a warning in the status report:

> The following changes were detected in the entity type and field definitions.
>   taxonomy_term entity type :
>   The Moderation state field needs to be installed.

But without the drush `entity-update`, I have no idea what I'm supposed to do here. How do I perform the update? Drush `dbup` ran successfully (and now reports no outstanding updates), which drush `entup` doesn't work anymore. How can I handle this error?

For the record, this is the output of the first drush updb, not sure if it's relevant:

```
server:~/httpdocs$ drush updb
 ------------------- ----------------------------------------------- --------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  Module              Update ID                                       Type            Description                                                                  
 ------------------- ----------------------------------------------- --------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  system              8701                                            hook_update_n   Remove the unused 'system.theme.data' from state.                            
  system              8702                                            hook_update_n   Add the 'revision_translation_affected' entity key.                          
  file                8700                                            hook_update_n   Set the 'owner' entity key and update the field.                             
  node                8700                                            hook_update_n   Set the 'owner' entity key and update the field.                             
  taxonomy            8701                                            hook_update_n   Add an index on the 'taxonomy_term__parent' field table.                     
  menu_link_content   make_menu_link_content_revisionable             post-update     Update custom menu links to be revisionable.                                 
  system              add_expand_all_items_key_in_system_menu_block   post-update     Initialize 'expand_all_items' values to system_menu_block.                   
  system              clear_menu_cache                                post-update     Clear the menu cache.   @see https:www.drupal.orgprojectdrupalissues3044364  
  system              fix_jquery_extend                               post-update     Clear the library cache and ensure aggregate files are regenerated.          
  taxonomy            make_taxonomy_term_revisionable                 post-update     Update taxonomy terms to be revisionable.                                    
  taxonomy            remove_hierarchy_from_vocabularies              post-update     Remove the 'hierarchy' property from vocabularies.                           
  views               exposed_filter_blocks_label_display             post-update     Update exposed filter blocks label display to be disabled.                   
  views               make_placeholders_translatable                  post-update     Rebuild cache to allow placeholder texts to be translatable.                 
 ------------------- ----------------------------------------------- --------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

 Do you wish to run the specified pending updates? (yes/no) [yes]:
 > yes

 [notice] Update started: system_update_8701
 [ok] Update completed: system_update_8701
 [notice] Update started: system_update_8702
 [ok] Update completed: system_update_8702
 [notice] Update started: file_update_8700
 [ok] Update completed: file_update_8700
 [notice] Update started: node_update_8700
 [ok] Update completed: node_update_8700
 [notice] Update started: taxonomy_update_8701
 [ok] Update completed: taxonomy_update_8701
 [notice] Update started: menu_link_content_post_update_make_menu_link_content_revisionable
 [notice] Custom menu links have been converted to be revisionable.
 [ok] Update completed: menu_link_content_post_update_make_menu_link_content_revisionable
 [notice] Update started: system_post_update_add_expand_all_items_key_in_system_menu_block
 [ok] Update completed: system_post_update_add_expand_all_items_key_in_system_menu_block
 [notice] Update started: system_post_update_add_expand_all_items_key_in_system_menu_block
 [ok] Update completed: system_post_update_add_expand_all_items_key_in_system_menu_block
 [notice] Update started: system_post_update_clear_menu_cache
 [ok] Update completed: system_post_update_clear_menu_cache
 [notice] Update started: system_post_update_fix_jquery_extend
 [ok] Update completed: system_post_update_fix_jquery_extend
 [notice] Update started: taxonomy_post_update_make_taxonomy_term_revisionable
 [notice] Taxonomy terms have been converted to be revisionable.
 [ok] Update completed: taxonomy_post_update_make_taxonomy_term_revisionable
 [notice] Update started: taxonomy_post_update_make_taxonomy_term_revisionable
 [notice] Taxonomy terms have been converted to be revisionable.
 [ok] Update completed: taxonomy_post_update_make_taxonomy_term_revisionable
 [notice] Update started: taxonomy_post_update_make_taxonomy_term_revisionable
 [notice] Taxonomy terms have been converted to be revisionable.
 [ok] Update completed: taxonomy_post_update_make_taxonomy_term_revisionable
 [notice] Update started: taxonomy_post_update_make_taxonomy_term_revisionable
 [notice] Taxonomy terms have been converted to be revisionable.
 [ok] Update completed: taxonomy_post_update_make_taxonomy_term_revisionable
 [notice] Update started: taxonomy_post_update_make_taxonomy_term_revisionable
 [notice] Taxonomy terms have been converted to be revisionable.
 [ok] Update completed: taxonomy_post_update_make_taxonomy_term_revisionable
 [notice] Update started: taxonomy_post_update_make_taxonomy_term_revisionable
 [notice] Taxonomy terms have been converted to be revisionable.
 [ok] Update completed: taxonomy_post_update_make_taxonomy_term_revisionable
 [notice] Update started: taxonomy_post_update_remove_hierarchy_from_vocabularies
 [ok] Update completed: taxonomy_post_update_remove_hierarchy_from_vocabularies
 [notice] Update started: views_post_update_exposed_filter_blocks_label_display
 [ok] Update completed: views_post_update_exposed_filter_blocks_label_display
 [notice] Update started: views_post_update_exposed_filter_blocks_label_display
 [ok] Update completed: views_post_update_exposed_filter_blocks_label_display
 [notice] Update started: views_post_update_make_placeholders_translatable
 [ok] Update completed: views_post_update_make_placeholders_translatable
 [success] Finished performing updates.
```

Comment: See https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3053758

Comment: @4k4 Thanks! I use workbench moderation, so that is where the error is coming from. I thought it was related to the update to taxonomies (now being revisionable). So since the drupal issue you linked links to [this issue for workbench moderation](https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench_moderation/issues/3054765), I assume this will need to be addressed in an update to workbench moderation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use the new [Devel Entity Updates](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_entity_updates) module, which was built for this exact purpose:

> In [#2976035: Entity type CRUD operations must use the last installed entity type and field storage definitions](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2976035) the ability to run drush entup was removed, see [the related change record](https://www.drupal.org/node/3034742) for more details. This project aims to restore this functionality as a developer-only tool. This module depends on [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) and is not meant to be enabled in production environments or relied upon in deployment workflows.

Comment: Thanks, though I think that's a workaround, I'd still like to know if there's an "official" way this is supposed to be resolved.

Comment: The official way is for modules relying on the old way to explicitly write the code to make the updates happen in `hook_update_N`. All the gritty details are here: https://www.drupal.org/node/3034742

Comment: Thanks! I thought that, but I was confused because I assumed the error was coming from the core and wondered if I had forgotten a step when updating. But apparently it's coming from workbench moderation, so I'll just need to wait until they come through with an update.

Comment: ah ok, yeah I was wondering the same thing actually, seems like the sort of thing core would've solved before releasing!

Comment: How can I use this module? I tried to install it with composer but drush still gives the old error about the removed function.

Comment: You need to install the module too @user6329530 (`drush en devel_entity_updates`)

Comment: I am geting an error like  *In UpdateDBCommands.php line 110:
Drupal removed its automatic entity-updates API in 8.7. See https://www.drupal.org/node/3034742*. After enabling the `devel_entity_updates `and doing `drush entup`. Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Put it in an update hook again. Put it in the your_module_name.install file. (Make sure it existed already in the module when installed, otherwise put it in an other modules install file)

```
/**
 * Update- Create your_entity_name entity.
 */
function your_module_name_update_8002() {
  //check if the table exists first.  If not, then create the entity.
  if(!db_table_exists('your_entity_name')) {
    \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->clearCachedDefinitions();
    \Drupal::entityDefinitionUpdateManager()
      ->installEntityType(\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getDefinition('your_entity_name'));
  }
  else {
    return 'your_entity_name entity already exists';
  }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It returns and exception: Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: The "your_entity_name" entity type does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @MoritzLost, relying on `drush entup` is a workaround. The proper solution would be to rely on the WBM patch or wait for it to be released before updating to 8.7. More details available at https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_entity_updates/issues/3082442.